# Insert Calculated Field in Table as one String VBA - MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I need to open a Table(Unmatched); Create a New Field (ID); Use existing Fields to create a new unique String (hertz); then, finally, insert this new string Back into the Table's New Field.  I'm stuck 'cause I'm new.  Any nudge forward would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim Hertz As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Unmatched")
Set fld = tdf.CreateField("ID")
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Unmatched", dbOpenTable)

Do Until rst.EOF
hertz = rst![Accounting Document Item] & Mid(rst![JE Line Description], 20, 2) & Round(Abs(rst![Transaction Amount]), 0)

Debug.Print hertz 'immediate window check
---> DoCmd.RunSQL "?!?!?"
rst.MoveNext
Loop

Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

Set fld = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: rst.Edit, rst.Update (see Online help)

Comment: @Andre, thank you.  You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim Hertz As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Unmatched")
Set fld = tdf.CreateField("ID", dbText, 255)
tdf.Fields.Append fld

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Unmatched")

Do Until rst.EOF
    Hertz = rst![Accounting Document Item] & Mid(rst![JE Line Description], 20, 2) & Round(Abs(rst![Transaction Amount]), 0)
    Debug.Print Hertz
    rst.Edit
    rst!ID = Hertz
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

This is how I would do it in code.  An update query would be easier if you did not need to create the field on the fly.

Comment: Thank you @JJ32 for your answer and for correcting my code.  You've helped me greatly.  I'm learning, brother, but it's not easy.  Thank you, again.